# OpenERP v7 - How to limit the crm phone call records to user's company?

Tags: crm, odoo

In OpenERP v7, I have tried to add some domain force to some osv objects. All of them are working fine except crm.phonecall object. Here is the code i have added to restrict the access.

```
<record id="crm_phonecall_comp_rule" model="ir.rule">
<field name="name">CRM Phone Call MutliCompany</field>
<field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="crm.model_crm_phonecall"/>
<field eval="True" name="global"/>
<field name="domain_force">['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id','child_of',    [user.company_id.id])]</field>
</record>
```

These code don't work... Is there anything wrong in my code or is this a known issue in V7 against crm.phonecall object?

Regards
Sage

Comment: any error traceback ?